# AJAX/javascript not working second time through

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a web site that jQuery loads the app page into a div that's part of the index page.

The app page contains two DIVs.. 1) a search form, and 2) a results div.

Searching  jQuery loads the results into the results div. Each result has call-to-action buttons, which jQuery load into the results div (leaving the search bar alone). The user finishes the call-to-action form, and then jQuery loads into the results div a results page.

This works perfectly the first time, every time. However, if after the results page is loaded, and the user clicks search again from the search bar, I get to the page where the user must choose a call-to-action button, but a javascript error pops up.

The particular error for this is:

`TypeError: $('#cta-email').validate is not a function. (In '$('#cta-email').validate', '$('#cta-email').validate' is undefined)`

This error then makes it impossible to click anything else that's javascript-based. Refreshing the page fixes it, but I can't figure out what's causing this script to cause errors when going through a second time.

Other notes.. almost every page that gets loaded by jQuery has a `<script>` at the bottom. I've researched stuff about scripts not firing through AJAX loading, etc., etc., but I'm not sure if that's part of the issue or not, because, as I said, I can go through the entire function once, but when looping around, that's when errors come up.

If I'm missing any info that'll help solve this, let me know.

Comment: Show your code please

Comment: If i'm not wrong, this error demontrates that jQuery is not loaded on the page, try to put `<script>src/jquery.min.js</script>` on the top page in the head tag.

Comment: As `$('...').validate` isn't defined, it seems that the jQuery validation plugin breaks or simply isn't loaded the second time. Are there any other errors showing in the console, or do you have a live demo?

Comment: @vietnguyen09 jQuery must be loaded, since it doesn't throw an error about `$` being undefined.

Comment: @AntonAbilov A live demo can be found at [link](http://rocketlobby.com)

Comment: @vietnguyen09 jQuery, and all other scripts and css, are loaded in the index page of the site as an include right before the closing head tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked at the demo, the issue seems to be that the resources (jQuery and jQuery validate) are reloaded when the form is submitted. This breaks jQuery validate.

Here's a look at the Network Requests (after submitting the form):
[image: network requests]

You can see that `results` reloads the resources
After a look at `results`, we see the following problematic lines:

```
<script async defer src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB36Tx2kI7o_o4tPsdiVJBf_wyPEf6r2dc"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.14.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yes! I just saw that the CTA results page loaded all the head scripts/css again, so that was definitely the issue. Thank you!

Comment: No worries! Happy to help out.